# What is the difference between 愛しい【いとしい】 and 愛おしい【いとおしい】?

Tags: word-choice

What is the difference between 愛しい and 愛おしい?

If possible, can you give me some example sentences?

Thank you.

Comment: Can this help? https://hinative.com/en-US/questions/14793258

Answer (score 1):

As you can read in the following website (https://biz.trans-suite.jp/26489), both words are currently used with the same meaning. Though, いとおしい sounds more old, since it is indeed 古語 (old language), while いとしい is more 現代語 (current Japanese).